# How to compare and operate two adjacent elements in one list using stream in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The background is I have two String type variables str1 and str2 as inputs. At last I have to return a list that contains the consecutive prefix of str1 that smaller than the related prefix in str2.

I have the Java code like this:

```
public List<Character> getPrefix(String str1, String str2) {
    int index = 0;
    List<Character> res = new ArrayList<>();
    //str1 = "1243"
    //str2 = "2324"
    // The answer will be "12".

    while (index < str1.length() && index < str2.length() && str1.charAt(index) <= str2.charAt(index)) {
        res.add(str1.charAt(index));
        index++;
    } 

    return res;
}
//the return type could either be List<String> or List<Character>
```

I was asked to convert this code in stream without using while or for loop, just in stream method. I plan to convert this code like this

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(str1);
list.add(str2);
List<String> res = list.stream()
.filter()
.reduce();
```

I found `filter()` method could select the element that match the given predicate, and `reduce()` method could use identity and accumulator to get one final result.

But I find I could neither have a way to operate two adjacent elements in one list, or get one pointer to compare and traverse each character in each element in the list(the element is String type).

So is there any ways that I could operate two adjacent elements in one list, so that I can compare their characters which in the same position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

1. Generate a stream of indexes
2. Get characters of both strings using the index
3. Select chars while valid

   ```
   // The magic
   public static List<Character> getPrefix(String str1, String str2) {

       return IntStream
           .range(0, Math.min(str1.length(), str2.length()))
           .mapToObj(i -> new char[] { str1.charAt(i), str2.charAt(i) })
           .takeWhile(a -> a[0] < a[1])
           .map(a -> a[0])
           .collect(Collectors.toList());

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code and maybe that is what you want.
Still it could be enhanced more and do not solve the case when first string start with a  value greater than second. This can be implemented also but need additional work.
(could not do in one piece because the supplier consume one element for check needed to chain dropWhile and takeWhile). 
Simply, with a supplier you can do comparison between elements from the stream with elements from other data-structure.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Pre1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Pre1().getPre("1234", "2315"));
        System.out.println(new Pre1().getPre("941234", "712315"));
        System.out.println(new Pre1().getPre("2345", "341"));   
    }

    public String getPre(String s1, String s2) {
        //second list is used as supplier
        LinkedList<Integer> l2 = s2.chars().boxed()
            .map(t->Character.getNumericValue(t))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList<Integer>::new));
        //l2.forEach(System.out::println);
        Supplier<Integer> supplier = () -> {
        //   System.out.println(l2.peek());
             return l2.isEmpty() ? 0 : l2.pollFirst();
        };

        return s1.chars().boxed()
             .map(t->Character.getNumericValue(t))
             .takeWhile(t->t<supplier.get())
             .map(t->String.valueOf(t))
             .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
}
```

Output

```
12
nothing 
23
```

Comment: Good solution, Thank you for the answer.